# RMI example and ExportException

Tags: java, rmi

Good day everybody!
I have problem, with my RMI example.
Week ago, i try to start my first example of RMI, and it's worked, but i delete project, and try to create again, but i can't,cos' throw ExportException.
What did i do wrong? Maybe i need to restart rmiregistry.exe or something else?

```
public interface IExample extends Remote {
    public String getMessage(String input) throws RemoteException;
}

public class ExampleImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IExample {
    public ExampleImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String input) throws RemoteException {
        return "Hi " + input + "!!!";
    }
  public static void main(String... args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        String name = "myexample";
        IExample engine = new ExampleImpl();
        IExample stub =
                (IExample) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 1090);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.rebind(name, stub);
}
}
```

P.s. Thx for all and sorry for my English.
P.p.s. and for my stupid question.

Comment: You should always post the exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class which extends UnicastRemoteObject is automatically exported on construction. You don't have to do it yourself. Remove the exportObject() call.

Comment: I remove this call, and get this Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Comment: Get rid of the security manager. You don't need it unless you're using the codebase feature.